# "...?ecver=x..." parameter on the youtube embed URL

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I've Noticed when embedding Youtube videos the following 2 URLs achieve the same result:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/ML1AyQC2HKM?ecver=2&modestbranding=1&rel=0`
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/kwdRYaBUco4?modestbranding=1&rel=0`

[embeded youtube video with parameter set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoON0.gif)

What does the `ecver` parameter on the youtube embed URL set ?

After checking [The Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) and searching the internet I couldn't seem to find anything to explain this parameter.

The name would suggest its setting the *Ecmascript version*? but this is just a stab in the dark and i can't seem to find anything to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ecver=1 can be deleted. This is a forced display at the top of the video title, + watch later, + share.

Answer (score 0):

The `ecver=2` is for getting rid of ads on pausing the video - like the `rel=0` is for having no ads at the end of the video, but this seems to work no more.